# HTTP failure during parsing for mailto.api

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project that includes a contact page where I have set up a html template that resembles this:

```
<section class="hero is-primary is-bold">
  <div class="hero-body">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="title">Contact Us!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="section">
  <div class="container">

    <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm(contactForm.value)" #contactForm = "ngForm">

      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Enter Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="input" [(ngModel)]="name" #nameInput="ngModel" required>
        <div class="help is-error" *ngIf="nameInput.invalid && nameInput.touched">
          Your Name Is Required In This Field
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Enter Valid Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="input" [(ngModel)]="email" #emailInput="ngModel" required email>
        <div class = "help is-error" *ngIf = "emailInput.invalid && emailInput.touched">
          A Valid Email Is Required In This Field
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Enter Message:</label>
        <textarea name="message" class="textarea" [(ngModel)]="message"></textarea>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button is-large is-warning" [disabled] = "contactForm.invalid">Submit</button>

    </form>

  </div>
</section>
```

I also have a contact model that looks like this:

```
export interface Contact {
    email : string;
    fullname : string;
    message : string;
}
```

In my component I was planning on creating a submitForm() method that takes in a Contact object and then passing the information from the form to an email designated by the mailto.api

For example: "https://mailthis.to/apikey"

Here is my code for my contact component:

```
export class ContactpageComponent implements OnInit {

   name : string;
   email : string;
   message : string;

 httpOptions = {headers: new HttpHeaders({"Content-Type" : "application/json"})};

 constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }


 ngOnInit() {

}

 submitForm(contact : Contact) {
 this.http.post<Contact>('mailtoaddress', contact).subscribe(status => 
           console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));

}
  
}
```

Could anyone help with the issue I am encountering?